# Styling select options

Tags: html, css, html-select

I have this:

[image: Annoying blue border and highlight]

I would like the highlight and the border around the options box not to be blue, which seems to be the system default. Is there a way to style the select options via CSS, or does the system control this?

As you can see, I was able to style the background and the font, it's just the annoying blue colour that bugs me.

I'm not interested in jQuery solutions (already using jQuery Uniform and I'm quite happy with it). I don't care about it looking the same across all browsers. Even if only certain browsers (Firefox & Chrome) can be targeted, I'll be satisfied.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't possible as the select color is OS specific, not browser. You will have to resort to some Javascript library to allow you to do this.

[Something like this](http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/) might help, but as you said you're not interested in JS solutions, unfortunately you'll have to live with the blue,

Comment: I see, well, thank you, that's what @sarcastyx said in his comment below the other answer and I guess this confirms that. I'll live with the blue, even though it looks a bit lame. BTW, @Kyle, thanks for the link. Even the form styling thing leaves the options the same way as jQuery.uniform does (and that' what I used), the resource itself is definitely interesting.