# How to change background color of the select tag options on hover?

Tags: css, html-select, background-color

I want to change the default system color (blue) while hovering the options in a select list box.

Are there any possibilities?

```
option:hover{ background:black; }
```

The above does not work for me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Styling select options](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789295/styling-select-options)

Answer (score 1):

This is impossible without javascript solutions as the background color of the element is determined by the Operating System (Windows, Mac, Ubuntu etc) and not the browser or elements within the website.

You will have to seek out [javascript or jQuery](http://www.devirtuoso.com/2009/08/styling-drop-down-boxes-with-jquery/) (or any other library) solutions :)

Comment: Actually, it can change between browsers too. I have a theme installed in Opera and its default select option highlight is grey. You can't override it though.

Comment: Aye, Opera is special as it employs such changes through the use of Javascript for it's theming feature :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

> select:hover { color: ? }

That may work in some browsers, won't work in IE<=6 without js because they don't accept :hover except on anchors and even then probably won't work. There's some aspects of form styling that just won't work cross browser.

Comment: Confirmed this does not have an effect in Chromium or Firefox on OpenBSD. Definitely OS specific.

Answer (score -1):

Try this one

```
 input:focus, select:focus, select:active, select option, select option:focus, select option:active, textarea:focus {
background: #fff4fc;
```

}

Comment: The color is rendered by the OS, not the browser. This isn't going to work without a Javascript solution.