# Multiple Styles In Option Element

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Styling select options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789295/styling-select-options)

I am wondering if it is possible to apply two styles within an `option` element? For example, in my code below, I would like my product name to be of style `color:black;` while the price be of another style `color:red; font-weight:bold;`. I have tried wrapping my price around `span.price` but that did not work.

```
<select>
  <option>Apple  <span class="price">$1.00</span></option>
  <option>Banana <span class="price">$2.50</span></option>
  <option>Cherry <span class="price">$1.50</span></option>
</select>
```

Comment: @Diodeus Sorry, I missed that thread :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`option` styles are styled in a way native to the platform. You cannot do what you desire without changing the markup (and/or using JavaScript)

Comment: That's what I thought :( Thank you for verifying my hunch.

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS in the  of your HTML document, or in your external stylesheet (strip out the `<style>` tags if you put it in an external stylesheet):

```
<style type="text/css">
select option { color: black; }
select option span.price { color: red; font-weight:bold; }
</style>
```

By doing this, you are basically saying "All options in my select should have black text color". Then, you're overriding that by saying "Any spans with a class of "price" inside an option inside my select should have a red text color."